# Has Dumbledore ever scolded Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

We see in both books and movies that Harry Potter is Dumbledore's golden boy. Their relationship was more of a personal thing. Dumbledore was more like a mentor than a headmaster to Harry and Dumbledore makes sure that Harry is safe. The boy knows this that he is there for him if anything happens. Every time that happens in Hogwarts Harry is the target. (Of course, he is the main character of the franchise). Let me quote from the fifth book:

> *"I cared about you too much. I cared more for your happiness than your knowing the truth, more for your peace of mind than my plan, more for your life than the lives that might be lost if the plan failed. In other words, I acted exactly as Voldemort expects we fools who love to act."*

**But given his role as a Headmaster of Hogwarts, has Dumbledore ever scolded Harry out of discipline and justice with the other students?** We see it in both movies and books that Harry is stubborn at times like he breaks the rule always. Dumbledore even pointed out in *The Chamber of Secrets* that Harry has a some parallelism of Salazar Slytherin who has a certain disregard of rules. I can only remember that Dumbledore ever scolded Potter is in the *Goblet of Fire* (Film). When his name got in that Goblet, the Headmaster shouted. And of course, the most famous one which among fans didn't like it.

[image]

Comment: upvote for the gif alone

Comment: Dumbledore claims to care for Harry's happiness, but his actions show that he doesn't.

Comment: @RalfFriedl - How so? I disagree.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath He even admits it: "You had suffered. I knew you would when I left you on your aunt and uncle’s doorstep. I knew I was condemning you to ten dark and diffi­cult years." (OotP)

Comment: @RalfFriedl: it seems that he considered he didn't have any better option.

Comment: @Taladris - didn't have an option he liked better than abusing a child till he commits suicide for his so-called greater good, yeah, sure.  Actions, not words.

Comment: @NKCampbell DIDYAPUTYOUTNAMEGOBLETOFFIYAHHH!!! 
He asked calmly.

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  But, at least in the later years, Professor Dumbledore humiliates Harry by delivering choice words in a calm manner.  This is more effective than if he shouted insults at him like Professor Snape did in his worst moments.  The best example is in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* chapter 20.

> Dumbledore heaved a deep sigh, then said, ‘But never mind my staff problems. We have much more important matters to discuss. Firstly – have you managed the task I set you at the end of our previous lesson?’
>
> ‘Ah,’ said Harry, brought up short. What with Apparition lessons and Quidditch and Ron being poisoned and getting his skull cracked and his determination to find out what Draco Malfoy was up to, Harry had almost forgotten about the memory Dumbledore had asked him to extract from Professor Slughorn … ‘Well, I asked Professor Slughorn about it at the end of Potions, sir, but, er, he wouldn't give it to me.’
>
> There was a little silence.
>
> ‘I see,’ said Dumbledore eventually, peering at Harry over the top of his half-moon spectacles and giving Harry the usual sensation that he was being X-rayed. ‘And you feel that you have exerted your very best efforts in this matter, do you? That you have exercised all of your considerable ingenuity? That you have left no depth of cunning unplumbed in your quest to retrieve the memory?’
>
> ‘Well,’ Harry stalled, at a loss for what to say next. His single attempt to get hold of the memory suddenly seemed embarrassingly feeble.  ‘Well … the day Ron swallowed love potion by mistake I took him to Professor Slughorn. I thought maybe if I got Professor Slughorn in a good enough mood –’
>
> ‘And did that work?’ asked Dumbledore.
>
> ‘Well, no, sir, because Ron got poisoned –’
>
> ‘– which, naturally, made you forget all about trying to retrieve the memory; I would have expected nothing else, while your best friend was in danger. Once it became clear that Mr Weasley was going to make a full recovery, however, I would have hoped that you returned to the task I set you. I thought I made it clear to you how very important that memory is. Indeed, I did my best to impress upon you that it is the most crucial memory of all and that we will be wasting our time without it.’
>
> A hot, prickly feeling of shame spread from the top of Harry's head all the way down his body. Dumbledore had not raised his voice, he did not even sound angry, but Harry would have preferred him to yell; this cold disappointment was worse than anything.
>
> ‘Sir,’ he said, a little desperately, ‘it isn't that I wasn't bothered or anything, I've just had other – other things …’
>
> ‘Other things on your mind,’ Dumbledore finished the sentence for him. ‘I see.’
>
> Silence fell between them again, the most uncomfortable silence Harry had ever experienced with Dumbledore; it seemed to go on and on, punctuated only by the little grunting snores of the portrait of Armando Dippet over Dumbledore's head. Harry felt strangely diminished, as though he had shrunk a little since he had entered the room.
>
> When he could stand it no longer he said, ‘Professor Dumbledore, I'm really sorry. I should have done more … I should have realised you wouldn't have asked me to do it if it wasn't really important.’

Comment: I've always loved that little interaction. Dumbledore clearly understands Harry's character: Harry does not like disappointing his friends. And that Dumbledore never raises his voice towards Harry makes him feel as if he's almost betrayed Dumbledore's trust. Dumbledore likely realizes this. It's almost... manipulative.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq What about Dumbledore's manipulations is "almost"? Dumbledore never even explains why he thinks Harry is more likely to succeed in that task than Dumbledore himself.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq It would be manipulative (only) if it weren't genuine.

Comment: I'm honestly confused which has the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

In Chapter Five of *Chamber of Secrets* Dumbledore scolds Harry and Ron (albeit without raising his voice) for flying the car to Hogwarts:

> "Not today, Mr. Weasley," said Dumbledore. "But I must impress upon both of you the seriousness of what you have done. I will be writing to both your families tonight. I must also warn you that if you do anything like this again, I will have no choice but to expel you."

In Chapter Twenty-Five *Half-Blood Prince* Dumbledore scolds Harry (again without raising his voice) for insisting that Malfoy is up to something and Dumbledore is not taking it seriously:

> "Enough," said Dumbledore. He said it quite calmly, and yet Harry fell silent at once; he knew that he had finally crossed some invisible line. "Do you think that I have once left the school unprotected during my absences this year? I have not. Tonight, when I leave, there will again be additional protection in place. Please do not suggest that I do not take the safety of my students seriously,Harry."
>
> "I didn't –" mumbled Harry, a little abashed, but Dumbledore cut across him.
>
> "I do not wish to discuss the matter any further."

Comment: The last quote is from the night when then Death Eaters invade Hogwarts. It's not so much scolding as it is the argument of authority against facts.

Comment: Your second example is not a valid one at all. Harry did not do anything wrong by bringing up Malfoy. In fact, Harry was correct to suspect some danger was coming. Even Dumbledore did not foresee that Malfoy would actually succeed in breaching the protection that Dumbledore placed on Hogwarts! Nor was Dumbledore scolding Harry for crossing the line; he merely was cutting Harry off from what he thought was unnecessary for Harry to worry about, partly because he did not want to reveal that Snape was already under his instruction to keep an eye on Malfoy.

Comment: @user21820 The "scolding" was not for bringing it up; it was for crossing the line by repeatedly harping on it and ignoring Dumbledore's assurances that everything was fine, and perhaps worst of all for insinuating that Dumbledore didn't care about the well-being of his students.

Comment: @Alex: I understand that line of thought, but I was saying that Dumbledore had other motives for cutting off Harry at that point, and I am not convinced he really wanted to scold Harry for the reason you gave. Remember that he already got Snape to agree to kill him if Malfoy couldn't do it, and at all costs he cannot reveal this to anyone else, not even Harry. When Harry says that Malfoy is up to something, Dumbledore thought it was to kill him (which he already knew). So it seems to me that this is a very compelling for him to shut down any inquiry that might expose why he was not concerned.

Comment: @user21820 Fair enough. But I would still consider it "scolding" since he rebukes Harry for continuing his line of inquiry, regardless of the motivation to avoid the topic.

Comment: Fair enough; I retract "not a valid one at all" and replace it with "not a very clear one". (By the way, I didn't downvote your answer as your first example was a good one in my opinion.) =)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't know if this meets your definition of "scolded," but here are some instances (really just the one scene) from *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* Chapter 23 Horcruxes: (emphases mine)

> “Harry, Harry, only because Voldemort made a grave error, and acted on Professor Trelawney’s words! If Voldemort had never murdered your father, would he have imparted in you a furious desire for revenge? **Of course not!** If he had not forced your mother to die for you, would he have given you a magical protection he could not penetrate? **Of course not, Harry! Don’t you see?** Voldemort himself created his worst enemy, just as tyrants everywhere do! Have you any idea how much tyrants fear the people they oppress? All of them realize that, one day, amongst their many victims, there is sure to be one who rises against them and strikes back! Voldemort is no different! Always he was on the lookout for the one who would challenge him. He heard the prophecy and he leapt into action, with the result that he not only handpicked the man most likely to finish him, he handed him uniquely deadly weapons!”
>
> “But —”
>
> “**It is essential that you understand this!**” said Dumbledore, standing up and striding about the
>   room, his glittering robes swooshing in his wake; **Harry had never seen him so agitated.**

and

> "...you have never been seduced by the Dark Arts, never, even for
>   a second, shown the slightest desire to become one of Voldemort’s followers!”
>
> “Of course I haven’t!” said Harry **indignantly**. “He killed my mum and dad!”
>
> “You are protected, in short, by your ability to love!” said Dumbledore **loudly**.

and

> “But, sir,” said Harry, making valiant efforts not to sound argumentative, “it all comes to the same thing, doesn’t it? I’ve got to try and kill him, or —”
>
> “**Got to?**” said Dumbledore. “**Of course you’ve got to!** But not because of the prophecy! Because you, yourself, will never rest until you’ve tried! We both know it! Imagine, please, just for a moment, that you had never heard that prophecy! How would you feel about Voldemort now? **Think!**”

and finally

> “I’d want him finished,” said Harry quietly. “And I’d want to do it.”
>
> “**Of course you would!**” **cried** Dumbledore

---

So he certainly gets agitated and frustrated that Harry doesn't understand in this moment. Whether it's a *scolding* or not, you decide. However, in general, Dumbledore seems to be a calm and logical fellow. He *is* a genius, after all!

Comment: Aren't some of those quotes from *Order of the Phoenix*? It would be great if you gave chapter numbers.

Comment: @b_jonas - Nope, they're all from HBP!

Comment: @b_jonas - I added the chapter they're from...